# Changing custom paper size from 0x0in?

Tags: printing, pdf, okular

I am trying to print a 5.7x11.2in pdf document in Okular. When I go into print I get the option to chose a size of paper at the bottom of which is the option 'custom'. However, when I click on this it turns the  page size to 0x0in and does not let me change it. So does anyone know how I can change this custom size to 5.7x11.2in?

Comment: Quick (although not ideal) way round it is to print the document form document viewer instead.